# Having issues getting the SUM() of a column with GROUP BY and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select distinct ProdQty, JobCompletionDate, JobHead.JobNum from erp.JobHead 
inner join erp.LaborDtl on JobHead.JobNum = LaborDtl.JobNum and JobHead.Company = LaborDtl.Company
where JobCompletionDate = '2022-01-04' and JobHead.Company = 'TD' and LaborDtl.JCDept ='MS'
```

It returns the `ProdQty` for every `JobNum` for a given `JobCompletionDate`
Here is an excerpt of that result:

| Prod Qty | JobCompletionDate | JobNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-01-04 | 198583 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 205388 |
| 2 | 2022-01-04 | 205562 |

I'm not going to paste the whole table here, but I hope the idea is clear. The reason I do `distinct` in the selection is because there are usually duplicate entries for the `ProdQty`, and using `distinct` eliminates those.

Next, I need to `GROUP BY` `JobCompletionDate` to get the total of `ProdQty` for that date. I am having issues using `SUM()` on the `ProdQty` field. When I sum the values from this column using Excel or a calculator, I get the value 7201, which is the **correct** value that I need.

However, when I perform this query:

```
select sum(distinct ProdQty) from erp.JobHead 
inner join erp.LaborDtl on JobHead.JobNum = LaborDtl.JobNum and JobHead.Company = LaborDtl.Company
where JobCompletionDate = '2022-01-04' and JobHead.Company = 'TD' and LaborDtl.JCDept ='MS'
group by JobCompletionDate
```

My result is: 6660

Why? What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Without seeing the data, my assumption is the distinct is now being removed and the sum is now summing all records INCLUDING the duplicates that the distinct was dropping off the record set

Comment: Looks like you can (and should) use `exists` in stead of `join` to avoid duplicates altogether. I think the distinct removes too many ProdQty's, also the ones that are no real duplicates. (If the second row had 12 too, would that be a duplicate?).

Comment: A good erp system shouldn't have duplicate labor quantities. Why do you think you have duplicates rather than simply multiple records for laborDtl that happen to record the same quantities?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a code-smell: a sign of poorly thought through joins. As mentioned, you probably need `EXISTS` or `IN` semi-join. If really necessary, you might need to place the `DISTINCT` in a CTE/derived table and then `SUM` the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
select distinct ProdQty, JobCompletionDate, JobHead.JobNum...
```

is deciding what is distinct very differently than this:

```
select sum(distinct ProdQty)...
```

In the first example, it's removing duplicates where the combination of ProdQty, JobCompletionDate, and JobHead.JobNum are not distinct.

In the second example, it's removing duplicates where just ProdQty is not distinct. Since it's removing too many rows with the distinct as it's specified, the sum comes out lower than expected.

What you want to do is deduplicate the rows the way you know it's working (assuming that's the first query) and then perform the sum off of that intermediate result. You could use a CTE or subselect to do that. Here's an example:

```
select sum(ProdQty) from 
(
select distinct ProdQty, JobCompletionDate, JobHead.JobNum from erp.JobHead 
inner join erp.LaborDtl on JobHead.JobNum = LaborDtl.JobNum and JobHead.Company = LaborDtl.Company
where JobCompletionDate = '2022-01-04' and JobHead.Company = 'TD' and LaborDtl.JCDept ='MS'
);
```

Comment: I am actually an idiot for not realizing my mistake here - thanks!!!